# Feature config class in android library project

Tags: android

I'm using a Config class with a bunch of boolean constants in an android library project, which toggle certain features in the code, and I have many projects that use that library, but need to define their own configs, so a Config file is present in these projects also. The problem is that the build fails, because the library and the project both have a Config.java class. This used to work, but as of ADT 17 the library Config class is not overridden.

How can I solve this problem now?

Answer (score 0):

Use the full packagename in the definition of the Config class, so example android.app.Activity instead of Activity.

Comment: The problem is that it gives a build error, when building the project, because both the Library and the Project define the Config file with the same packagename, and the library jar already has that class.